# Is it possible to use type `char` in an account field / as funciton arguments?

Tags: anchor, deserialization, serialization

The goal is to use to use the char type.

I couldn't find a way or ressource on how to solve to borsh serialization errors that get thrown when trying to store a char type in an #[account] struct field.

Other types or enums won't make problems.

A reproduction is as simple as taking any anchor project and defining one of the fileds of an account to be type of `char`. E.g. when using one of the example projects from the [anchor repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor) and adding a char field it will produce an error:

```
#[account]
pub struct Counter {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub count: u64,
    pub something: char, // <- will produce error
}
```

To take an example from one of the projects I'm working on:
[image: char field]
[image]

Error msg:

```
rustc: the trait bound `char: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
  &T
  ()
  (T0, T1)
  (T0, T1, T2)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
and 185 others
see issue #48214
```

Also trying to use a char as a function argument throws errors for the #[program] macro.

Project in screenshots: https://github.com/tobealive/anchor-solana-twitter/

Comment: provide the nonworking code and any error message(s) you're receiving

Comment: Added an example, screenshots and an error message.

Comment: Why not use an u8 instead of a char? its the same

Comment: How is u8 and char the same? Lets say the char should represent an utf8 character like an emoji. The char type is capabale of that. u8 on the other is only for 8bit integers or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: I assumed you want to store an ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` in rust is not considered serializable by the [Borsh spec](https://borsh.io/) which anchor uses. This is because a char is really an array of 4 bytes with many invalid values.

Depending on your use case you can use a string that you then take the first character of only or store a 4 byte array that you utf8 encode into and out of. It's very likely though that you really need a char stored. If you elaborate on the use case there may be a better solution.

A more extreme option would be to extend borsh yourself by storing a wrapped value and implementing `BorshSerialize` for that. You will need to manually deserialize it on the client side and anchor doesn't usually like custom types.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light onto this. The goal of the question turned to understand why it is not possible to use the char type in general and if there is a way to solve it.
For the specific `char`-use-case in the app: Just a predefined set of chars had to be stored. A good solution was to use an enum instead of a char type. The enum variants describe the allowed characters, and a validation function matches / evaluates them to the corresponding characters. It's the 'reaction' part of the app.